# Getting SharePoint ClientContext in HTML page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, csom

I'm trying to fetch **SharePoint** client context form a HTML page. I have added the *sp.js, sp.core.js, sp.runtime.js, init.js, MicrosoftAjax.js* to the page.

But every time it gives me error as:

```
 "Object doesn't support property or method 'get_staticObjects'".
```

There is a catch to this. When I load the *sp.js* after loading all other scripts I get a different error:

```
 "Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Parameter name: serverRelativeUrl".
```

This error pops up even though I have used the full url i.e. https://...

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://allthatjs.com/2012/04/03/using-sharepoint-csom-in-html5-apps/) page.

Comment: Try using REST API instead of ClientContext so you dont run into these issues. When your API calls the resourse you have to authenticate first and thats it you have your data.